# How to print key and values from dictionaries enlisted in array, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, printing

I am having difficulties printing data from dictionaries stored in an array using double for-loop with

```
var residents = [{name: "Pyrus", room: "32"},{name: "Ash Ketchum", room: "22"}];

function people() {
    for (let i = 0; i < residents.length; i++) {
        for (let j in residents[i]) {
            document.write(j + ": " + residents[j] + "<br>");
        }
    }
};

people();
```

What I am retrieving is this:

```
name: undefined 
room: undefined
name: undefined
room: undefined
```

I can print the key but it seems like it does not fetch value defined to the key! 
What am I doing wrong?

A success criteria is to print in HTML.

Comment: should be `residents[i][j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chained two loops together so your function needs to access the parents index then the property that you wish to reference.

```
function people() {
    for (let i = 0; i < residents.length; i++) {
        for (let j in residents[i]) {
            document.write(j + ": " + residents[i][j] + "<br>");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way I think(Use [`foreach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)):

```js
var residents = [{name: "Pyrus", room: "32"},{name: "Ash Ketchum", room: "22"}];

function people() {
    residents.forEach(function(resident) {
 document.write(resident.name + ": " + resident.room + "<br>");
});

}
people();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not try like this with [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var residents = [{
  name: "Pyrus",
  room: "32"
}, {
  name: "Ash Ketchum",
  room: "22"
}];

function people(residents) {
  residents.forEach((element) => {
    for (var key in element) {
      if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + ':' + element[key]);
      }
    }
  });

};
people(residents);
```

Comment: @mhodges Yeah, I write them verbosely, I can make it compact within 8lines though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid some of the `for` loops and make the code a little easier to read using `forEach` and `Object.entries`:

```js
var residents = [{name: "Pyrus", room: "32"},{name: "Ash Ketchum", room: "22"}];

residents.forEach(res => {
    Object.entries(res).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key + ": " + value ); //subing console.log so it prints here
    //document.write(key + ": " + value + "<br>");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `residents[i][j]` since you are iterating residents in the first place.

so your code becomes :

`document.write(j + ": " + residents[i][j] + "<br>");`

See this [working js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo1m07us/)

You could also write it like this :

```
function people(){
    residents.forEach(r => {
        for(let j in r){
          document.write(j + ": " + r[j] + "<br>");
      }
    })
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @lealceldeiro: Probably because that's not the correct use case for using `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular for-loop it would go like the below code. Also, I strongly recommend you to check if all the properties (`j`) are own properties (with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)), otherwise this will look up in the prototype chain. This can be a problem if the objects are added to the array dynamically, otherwise you can bypass this check.

```js
var residents = [{name:"Pyrus",room:"32"},{name: "Ash Ketchum",room:"22"}];

function people() {
  for (let i = 0; i < residents.length; i++) {
    for (let j in residents[i]) {
      if (residents[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) { // <-- check if it is an own property!
        document.write(j + ": " + residents[i][j] + "<br>");
        //first access the object in residents[i], for example {name: "Pyrus",room: "32"}, then to its properties-values with residents[i][j]
      }
    }
  }
};

people();
```